# Aligned brackets in vertical in a sheet

Tags: math-mode, brackets

How can I put the brackets aligned across the sheet and greater spacing between them vertically, to be readable by the teacher?(I need a more beautiful aesthetic appearance on the sheet because there are many brackets followed)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\begin{document}
$$\Leftrightarrow
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle \frac{259\times e_1}{4100}+\frac{4,1\times e_1}{4100}+
\frac{0,41\times e_1}{4100}=0,01+1\times10^{-3}+\frac{941}{1640}\\
\addlinespace\displaystyle 4705-517\times e_1=e_2\end{array} \right.
\Leftrightarrow
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle \frac{263,51\times e_1}{4100}=\frac{2997}{5125}\\
\addlinespace
\displaystyle 4705-517\times e_1=e_2\end{array}\right.\Leftrightarrow
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle e_1=\frac{\frac{2997}{5125}}{\frac{263,51}{4100}}\\ \addlinespace
\displaystyle 4705-517\times e_1=e_2\end{array}\right.$$
$$\Leftrightarrow\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle e_1=\frac{12287700}{1350488,75}=
\frac{239760}{26351}\, (dividiu-se\,por\,5125)\\ \addlinespace
\displaystyle e_2=4705-517\times \frac{239760}{26351}=
\frac{123981455}{26351}-\frac{123955920}{26351}
\end{array}\right.$$
$$\Leftrightarrow\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle e_1=\frac{12287700}{1350488,75}\\
\addlinespace
\displaystyle e_2=4705-517\times\frac{239760}{26351}=1
-\frac{123955920}{26351}
\end{array}\right.$$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Is this that you want?
I simplified you code and improved its look with the `\num` commabnd from `\siunitx` for log numbers. Note you never should use the plain TeX `$$ … $$` environment, but the LaTeX `\[ … \]` instead, and for multiline displays, one the `align`, `gather` or `multline` environments from `amsmath`. Here I used `align*` and `dcases` (display style cases) defined by amsmath very useful extension `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker ={,}}
 \usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
 &\iff
\begin{dcases}
 \frac{259\times e_1}{4100}+\frac{4,1\times e_1}{4100}+
\frac{0,41\times e_1}{4100}=0,01+1\times10^{-3}+\frac{941}{1640}\\
 4705-517\times e_1=e_2
\end{dcases} \\[1ex]
 &\iff
\begin{dcases}
 \frac{263,51\times e_1}{4100}=\frac{2997}{5125}\\
 4705-517\times e_1=e_2
\end{dcases}
\iff
\begin{dcases}
 e_1=\frac{\frac{2997}{5125}}{\frac{263,51}{4100}}\\
 4705-517\times e_1=e_2
 \end{dcases}\\[1ex]
 &\iff
\begin{dcases}
e_1=\frac{\num{12287700}}{\num{1350488,75}}=
\frac{239760}{26351}\quad \text{(dividiu-se\,por\,5125)}\\
e_2=4705-517\times \frac{\num{239760}}{\num{26351}}=
\frac{\num{123981455}}{\num{26351}}-\frac{\num{123955920}}{\num{26351}}
\end{dcases}\\[1ex]
 &\iff
 \begin{dcases}
 e_1=\frac{\num{12287700}}{\num{1350488,75}}\\
 e_2=4705-517\times\frac{\num{239760}}{\num{26351}}=1
-\frac{\num{123955920}}{\num{26351}}
\end{dcases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What mean [1ex] of the comand: \end{dcases}?

Comment: `\\[1ex]` adds a vertical spacing of  1ex to the row height (`ex` is the height of the letter x in the current font). It's better than adding a fixed height in pt or cm, because it adapts to the font in use.

Answer (score 2):

Initial considerations:

- I would not use `\addlinespace` unless I had first loaded the `booktabs` package.
- Use `\text` for your parenthetical comment.
- Your arrays are so big that you should consider having just one per line (as I do below).
- Instead of having several displayed math expressions, you should load `amsmath` and put everything in an `amsmath` environment that enables alignment.
- You can increase the vertical spacing within an array by modifying `arraystretch`, and within an alignment-enabling environment you can insert additional vertical space between lines by specifying an option after the `\\` newline-marker.

You should study the `amsmath` documentation and consider enclosing elements of your arrays in their own aligned environments, but maybe the following will set you on a good path:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3.0}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\Leftrightarrow
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
    \displaystyle \frac{259\times e_1}{4100}+\frac{4,1\times e_1}{4100}+
    \frac{0,41\times e_1}{4100}=0,01+1\times10^{-3}+\frac{941}{1640}\\
    \displaystyle 4705-517\times e_1=e_2%
\end{array}\right. \\[0.5cm]
&\Leftrightarrow
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
    \displaystyle \frac{263,51\times e_1}{4100}=\frac{2997}{5125}\\
    \displaystyle 4705-517\times e_1=e_2
\end{array}\right.\\[0.5cm]
&\Leftrightarrow
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
    \displaystyle e_1=\frac{\frac{2997}{5125}}{\frac{263,51}{4100}}\\ 
    \displaystyle 4705-517\times e_1=e_2
\end{array}\right. \\[0.5cm]    
&\Leftrightarrow
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
    \displaystyle e_1=\frac{12287700}{1350488,75}=
    \frac{239760}{26351}\, \text{(dividiu-se\,por\,5125)}\\
    \displaystyle e_2=4705-517\times \frac{239760}{26351}=
    \frac{123981455}{26351}-\frac{123955920}{26351}
\end{array}\right. \\[0.5cm]
&\Leftrightarrow
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
    \displaystyle e_1=\frac{12287700}{1350488,75}\\
    \displaystyle e_2=4705-517\times\frac{239760}{26351}=1
    -\frac{123955920}{26351}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see that a much more expert community member provided a superior answer just now.  Use @Bernard's refinements!

Comment: Although the `arraystretch` did space things out nicely ...

Comment: And I apologize for the small size of the image I provided.  The `standalone` package documentation is clear on how to set the converted image so it will show up well on Stack exchange, but I have not yet figured out how to make it work for me.